# How to allow ipod music to play while my app is running?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm using `SimpleAudioEngine` to play my sounds and I was wondering if there is anyway to check if iPod music is playing when the app is launched. If so, I want it to continue playing. I'm starting to think it may be called the simple engine for a reason as it doesn't allow features like this, where `AVAudioEngine` does...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the official [Audio Session Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and make sure that you are setting the correct session category. You will want to pick the category that allows your audio to mix with the iPod audio.